# steam not working on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04, steam

when trying to load steam from the terminal it displays

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437509903)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you are missing the files: `radeonsi_dri.so` and `swrast_dri.so`. Run the following commands to install those files:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Please post any errors.